# Allow "third party" plugins for my Django app, that don't require config changes?

Tags: python, django

I would like to know of a good approach, or programming "pattern" to apply, to allow users of my Django application to drop in "plugins" or "extensions" for my app, without having to add anything to 'installed apps' or edit any configuration.

WordPress plugins probably being the best example. New options/settings/menus become available, but I don't have to edit the WordPress config or core files - they just show up in my admin.

**In Django/Python, what approach or programming "pattern" would you use to begin to develop a type of plugin architecture?**

I know that WordPress (the example given) is a 'platform' itself, and provides a plugin API, etc. My question is about the patterns involved, and the early stages - preparing for plugins *before* the application is built, rather than trying to add that functionality later.

To be specific, my app accepts "content", and I'd like to provide a way for users to drop in modular "transformers" that provide **additional** outputs of that content (not just a filter) that may or may not need to accept a few basic settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use the Django signal system. Your app should send signals when certain actions occur and then listen to them when the next stage happens. If someone wants to change the behaviour of your app, all they would need to do would be to listen to the relevant signals that your app sends out and modify the data appropriately.

This allows for very easy expansion and change of applications without needing to even touch your apps source code.

I would make a point though, if someone is using your app it is unlikely to be installed in the project folder so requiring them to place code your apps folder is a bad idea. It will most likely be installed as a module within a virtualenv. Using the signals method I outlined above the person using your app can then just add the handlers in the app in their project that it makes most sense to place the handlers in. Thus they never need to touch your apps source code directory.

Comment: Using signals does remove the requirement for modular code to be place in any one particular place, however: Is there an elegant way to activate this modular code without a user adding it to "installed apps"? My alternative would be a "plugin management" feature where users can upload/activate/deactivate/delete these modules, and my apps initial load would simply import them (.py files?). I'm just not a python guru, so I'm not sure what's "acceptable" in that realm, or even the best practices with things like that.

Comment: @anonymous coward I think your requirement that people not add a new app to their install apps list is a bit unnecessary really. It means it forces them to add code to your existing code base making it much harder to upgrade if you ever release a newer version. It is always better to keep the original code and any additions or modifications separate if at all possible. See next comment.

Comment: @anonymous coward If you are determined though the traditional method is to have a group of methods that take call back functions in the users code which are then called by your code when certain actions take place. Thus the user provides the implementation of certain call back functions based on the data that you pass to them. This does require very good documentation though and makes it a pain to maintain as you can't easily change the API without breaking all previous modifications. If no user call back functions are provided you simply fall back to your own implementations of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a django-plugins in pypi that allows you to define "plugin points", making it easier to allow your app to have plugins.

See:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-plugins